# Shuffle Button with position Android

Tags: android

I have ten buttons in my xml layout i want to exchange the position of the 10 buttons randomly. I tried two methods to achieve it.

Method 1: I changed the background resource of the button but only the image changed. Not the button position on the layout. Here is my workings for method 1.

```
objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
objects.add(R.drawable.num_one);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_eight);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_six);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_five);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_nine);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_four);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_two);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_three);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_zero);
objects.add(R.drawable.num_seven);

// Shuffle the collection
Collections.shuffle(objects);

List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.name));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_eight));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_six));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_five));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.time));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_four));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_two));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.search_box));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_zero));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_seven));

for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    buttons.get(i).setBackgroundResource(objects.get(i));
}
```

In Method two: I shuffled the button directly but as the widget are already set in the xml layout. AddView () give an error message that the view is already set. Here is my working for the second solution.

```
        ll =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llShuffleBox);

        //create another two linear layouts which will host 5 buttons horizontally
        top_compte =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_compte);
        bottom_calculator=  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_calculator);

    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.name));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_eight));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_six));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_five));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.time));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_four));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_two));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.search_box));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_zero));
buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton_seven));
Collections.shuffle(buttons);
  for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
  top_compte.addView(buttons.get(i));
        }

  //add remaining 5 to second layout
        for (int i=5;i<10;i++){
        bottom_calculator.addView(buttons.get(i));
        }
      //  ll.addView(top_compte);
        ll.addView(bottom_calculator);
```

My question is how can i exchanged the position of the buttons on my layout. Note button 0 to 4 is in a horizontal linear layout and below it is the second horizontal linear layout containing button 5 to 9. Also ll is the Main LinearLayout that contain the two horizontal layout.

Comment: 1. Why do you declare `i` twice - see the two `for` loops - Put them in one loop and distinguish the value of `i` with `if{}else{}` statement. 2. Paste the LogCat output - how else can we guess the error. Thanks

Comment: What i understand is that you want to change the name of the button you can do it by using the method setText();and using setbackgraoundResources() for change the background am i right.as simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating the `Buttons` dynamically(in code). So, you'll have a `LinearLayout(vertical)` and two `LinearLayouts(horizontal)` within it. Keep your xml file as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llShuffleBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_compte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_calculator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, for the activity code:

```
ll =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llShuffleBox);

//create another two linear layouts which will host 5 buttons horizontally
top_compte =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_compte);
bottom_calculator=  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_calculator);

// Create an ArrayList to hold the Button objects that we will create    
ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

// Create the Buttons, set their text as numeral value of the index variable    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("" + (i+1));
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    buttonList.add(b);
}

// Shuffle    
Collections.shuffle(buttonList);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Add the first five Buttons to top_compte
    // Add the last five Buttons to bottom_calculator
    if (i < 5) {
        top_compte.addView(buttonList.get(i));
    } else {
        bottom_calculator.addView(buttonList.get(i));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Declare and initialize this global variable:

```
// Global variable
int id = 1;
```

Add the following method to your activity. It will generate an id that is not in use elsewhere in your view tree.

```
// Generates and returns a valid id that's not in use
public int generateUniqueId(){  
    View v = findViewById(id);  
    while (v != null){  
        v = findViewById(++id);  
    }  
    return id++;  
}
```

Change the code to set ids to buttons:

```
ll =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llShuffleBox);

//create another two linear layouts which will host 5 buttons horizontally
top_compte =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_compte);
bottom_calculator=  (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_calculator);

// Create an ArrayList to hold the Button objects that we will create    
ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

// Create the Buttons, set their text as numeral value of the index variable    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("" + (i+1));
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    b.setId(generateUniqueId());                    // Set an id to Button

    buttonList.add(b);
}

// Shuffle    
Collections.shuffle(buttonList);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    // Add the first five Buttons to top_compte
    // Add the last five Buttons to bottom_calculator
    if (i < 5) {
        top_compte.addView(buttonList.get(i));
    } else {
        bottom_calculator.addView(buttonList.get(i));
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the ids using the `getId()` method. If you do not want to use the `generateUniqueId()` method, you can try replacing the line `b.setId(generateUniqueId());` with `b.setId(i + 1);`. This will set the button ids from 1 to 10. But, it can be problematic if some view in your view hierarchy has the same id as any other.

**Edit 2:**

Here is how you can set the `OnClickListeners` to the Buttons you create dynamically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("" + (i+1));
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    b.setId(i + 1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dealWithButtonClick(b);
        }            
    });

    bList.add(b);

}
```

And here is one possible implementation of `dealWithButtonClick(Button)` method. You can change it to suit your needs:

```
public void dealWithButtonClick(Button b) {
    switch(b.getId()) {
      case 1: 
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable_1));
        break;
    case 2:
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable_2));
        break;

    ........

    ........

    ........

    case 10:
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable_10));
        break;
    default:
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable_for_when_no_cases_were_matched));
            break;        }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how can i get their id and set background on specific button

Comment: @Nikita Hey, I have edited the post above. Refer to **Edit 1**.

Comment: thanks you one last thing how can i setonclicklistener on the button id but gratitude

Comment: @Nikita No problem. I have updated the post with **Edit 2**. See if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Nikita Note that for this to work, you'll have to set the ids yourself. The code in Edit 2 sets them from 1 to 10. The numbers are irrelevant themselves, but keeping track of them is required. So, you can set random number as long as you can handle cases for them in the `dealWithButtonClick(Button)` method.

Comment: ok but i found a simpler way i just set b.setonclicklistener(this) after button b = new button and it works like charm thank you vikram

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem (shuffle buttons) and i come up with an easy solution
I just used an array of integer numbers of buttons ids and simple shufle. In my case was that enough. It's simple and u get the same result.

```
Integer[] a =  { 0x7f090049, 0x7f09004b, 0x7f09004c, 0x7f090048};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(a));

button1 = (Button)findViewById(a[0]);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(a[1]);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(a[2]);
button4 = (Button)findViewById(a[3]);
```

I hope this will help. 
Regards !!
(srry for my broken english)